# Formato de fecha en columna de jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy usando el plugin DataTables de jquery y me encuentro con un problema en las columnas de fecha.
Se me ven así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que me aparezcan en el formato dd/mm/yyyy y poder ordenar por estas columnas.
En el caso de la columna de la fecha de baja, creo que el valor que viene para muchas será MaxValue, en este caso, necesitaría que simplemente no mostrara nada.

El código javascript que tengo es algo así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#mitabla').DataTable({
     processing: true,  serverSide: true,  orderMulti: false,
     language: { url: "/Json/Spanish.json" },
     ajax: {
        url: "/Dattos/GetEmpresas",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json"
     },
     columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], visible: false, searchable: false },  //Clave primaria
        { targets: [1], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: true },  //Empresa
        { targets: [2], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //NIF
        { targets: [3], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //Fecha alta
        { targets: [4], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true }  //Fecha baja
     ],
     columns: [
        { data: "Id", name: "Id" },
        { data: "Nombre", name: "Nombre", title: "Empresa" },
        { data: "CIF", name: "CIF", title: "CIF" },
        { data: "FechaAlta", name: "FechaAlta", title: "Fecha de alta" },
        { data: "FechaBaja", name: "FechaBaja", title: "Fecha de baja" }
     ]
  });
});
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para mostrarlas correctamente y poder ordenar por ellas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado una solución que me funciona.
La pongo aquí por si a alguien más le es útil.

```
 columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], visible: false, searchable: false },  //Clave primaria
        { targets: [1], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //Empresa
        { targets: [2], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //NIF
        {
           targets: [3], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: true,
           render: function (value) {
              if (value === null) return "";
              var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/; //date format from server side
              var results = pattern.exec(value);
              var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
              if (dt.getFullYear() === 9999) return ""; //Control para MaxValue
              return ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ('0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
           }
        },  //Fecha alta
        {
           targets: [4], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: false,
           render: function (value) {
              if (value === null) return "";
              var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/; //date format from server side
              var results = pattern.exec(value);
              var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
              if (dt.getFullYear() === 9999) return ""; //Control para MaxValue
              return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
           }
        }  //Fecha baja
     ],
```

Comment: Muy bien, podrías incluso agregar como se muestra luego de usar tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo utilizando Serializer de .Net

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
json = js.Serialize(listclient);
```

Me mostraba la salida en Datatable de JQuery:

```
"Fecha_":"\/Date(1577426400000)\/"
```

Lo resolví cambiándome a Newtonsoft.Json.dll lo pueden descargar de la web:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listclient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que esta solución es más simple. Escribe esto dentro de las columnas del dataTable:

```
{
 "data": "nombre de mi columna", //este es el nombre que viene en JSON.
 render: function(data, type, row) {

   return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString(
   'es-CL', // modifica a tu idioma y país yo puse CL = Chile
       {
     year: 'numeric',
     month: 'numeric',
     day: 'numeric'
        }
    );
  }
},
```

---

- Antes: `1956-01-20 00:00:00`.
- Ahora quedará así: `20-01-1956`.

Hay que probar las diferentes opciones que da dataTables con el render y la siguiente línea:

- `return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString`